# MAUI Databinding with CommandParameter for SwipeItem and TapGestureRecognizer return null

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, maui, android-mvvm, maui-android

I follow the tutorial [.Net MAUI Full CRUD with SQLite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F31e4siUvV4&list=PLprnOV9ZLFnt8mtFGpLGDMCpPVajLzq22&index=10) to develop a feature in a MAUI app for CRUD with SQLite. I use **Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm** to fullfill MVVM requirements. But now when I click **Delete** button, nothing happens (fig 1). Also when I click **Edit** button (the edit icon), the values of selected line are not passed to the edit page (fig 2, supposing the seventh item is selected).

[image: Fig 1, main view]
[image]

Here are the related code

Models:

```
public class PartTag
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string modelID { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <RefreshView x:DataType="vm:PartTagPageViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadPartTagsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding partTagList}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:PartTag">
                    <StackLayout Padding="2">
                        <SwipeView>
                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PartTagPage}},Path=BindingContext.PartTagTappedDeleteCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="red" />
                                <SwipeItem IsDestructive="True" Text="Close" BackgroundColor="#05f0a5" />
                            </SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ID}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding modelID}" FontSize="Large" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding location}" FontSize="Large" />
                                <Image Source="edit.png" Grid.Column="3" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="End">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PartTagPage}},
                                            Path=BindingContext.PartTagTappedEditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</StackLayout>
```

ViewModels:

```
public partial class PartTagPageViewModel : BasePartTagViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PartTag> partTagList { get; }

    public PartTagPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        partTagList = new ObservableCollection<PartTag>();
        Navigation = navigation;
    }

    [ICommand]
    private async void OnAddPartTag()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AddPartTagPage));
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }

    [ICommand]
    private async Task LoadPartTags()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            partTagList.Clear();
            var partList = await App.PartTagService.GetAllAsync();
            foreach (var item in partList)
            {
                partTagList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally { IsBusy = false; }
    }

    [ICommand]
    private async void PartTagTappedDelete(PartTag partTag)
    {
        if (partTag==null)
        {
            return;
        }
        await App.PartTagService.DeleteAsync(partTag.ID);
        await LoadPartTags();
        OnAppearing();
    }


    
    [ICommand]
    private async void PartTagTappedEdit(PartTag partTag)
    {
        if (partTag == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new AddPartTagPage(partTag));
    }
}

public partial class BasePartTagViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public PartTag partTag;

    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class BaseViewModel:ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool _isBusy;
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string _title;
}
```

In the XAML, I also tried to change the **AncestorType** value to **vm:PartTagPageViewModel** and correspondingly change the **Path** value to **PartTagTappedDeleteCommand**. But the problem still exists.

Could someone point out where I did wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if you could access your database correctly? And what's the code of `AddPartTagPage`? If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github and share a link here?

Comment: Your communitytoolkit mvvm seems quite old.

Comment: @H.A.H. yes it is old. But I think it works because it works in the tutorial.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Yes, for that I have. I made it work after changing the command binding value to `Command="{Binding BindingContext.PartTagTappedDeleteCommand,Source={x:Reference thisPage}`. But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work after changing the command binding value.

```
Command="{Binding BindingContext.PartTagTappedDeleteCommand,Source={x:Reference thisPage}
```

With this command binding value, the delete button works now. But still I have no idea why.